# F# do let execution order

Tags: f#

I'm new to F# so this block of code seems strange to me

```
let randomTest avgWait avgBusyTime numExp numClients labsRules =
    let clients, _ = mkClientsAndLabs numClients labsRules 
    doTest [for i in 0..numClients-1 -> randomTestClient clients i avgWait avgBusyTime numExp  ]

do let clients, _ = mkClientsAndLabs 5 [rulesA; rulesB] 
   doTest [scheduledClient clients 0 [(0, 500, A)];     // Request a lab at the very start, use for "A" for 0.5 seconds
           scheduledClient clients 1 [(200, 300, Mix (Mix (A,Mix (A,A)),B))] ;   // Request after 0.2s, release 0.3s later.

           scheduledClient clients 2 [(300, 200, Mix (A,Mix (A,A)))];   // These three will all be waiting for a lab.
           scheduledClient clients 3 [(400, 200, Mix (A,A))];           // Client 2 should include the others as guests.
           scheduledClient clients 4 [(400, 200, A)]
          ]
```

What I am unsure is the `do let` declaration - it obviously is declared after `randomTest` yet `randomTest` can still call that function. What is the order of this code execution?

Comment: If any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The way it's written may be confusing. There is no such thing as a `do let` declaration.
In fact it's a whole `do {code}` block with a let binding inside the `{code}`.
That means it's not a function declaration, a do block is just a code to be executed, it does not declare functions or values.

Should be easier to read like this:

```
do 
   let clients, _ = mkClientsAndLabs 5 [rulesA; rulesB] 
   doTest [scheduledClient clients 0 [(0, 500, A)];     // Request a lab at the very start, use for "A" for 0.5 seconds
           scheduledClient clients 1 [(200, 300, Mix (Mix (A,Mix (A,A)),B))] ;   // Request after 0.2s, release 0.3s later.

           scheduledClient clients 2 [(300, 200, Mix (A,Mix (A,A)))];   // These three will all be waiting for a lab.
           scheduledClient clients 3 [(400, 200, Mix (A,A))];           // Client 2 should include the others as guests.
           scheduledClient clients 4 [(400, 200, A)]
          ]
```

So the order of execution is first `let randomTest ...`, then the `do` block.